# Как отследить событие на клик

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Карты Яндекса позволяют строить маршруты. По построенному маршруту можно вызвать такси, нажав на кнопку заказа.

Возможно ли отследить событие нажатия на кнопку **заказа такси**?

```
var myMap = new ymaps.Map(
    "map", {
        center: [44.998854, 39.066650],
        zoom: 16,
        height: 520,
        controls: ['routePanelControl']
    }
);

var control = myMap.controls.get('routePanelControl');
var location = ymaps.geolocation.get({
    provider: 'browser'
});

control.routePanel.options.set({
    types: {
        auto: true,
        taxi: true,
        pedestrian: true,
    }
});

control.routePanel.state.set({
    type: "taxi",
    from: [44.998854, 39.066650]
    to: 'Краснодар, Жилой квартал «Премьера»'
});
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Используйте слушателей для клика, а у каждой метки есть координаты.

Comment: @NikitaSmith дело в том, что я не пойму какому объекту вешать клик:)

Comment: Если бы пример приложил рабочий, было бы проще разговаривать.

Comment: @NikitaSmith обновил, после данного кода строится маршрут и открывается балун с кнопкой

Comment: а что вы хотите сделать после нажатия на кнопку "Заказать такси"?

Comment: @se0ga отправить цель в метрику

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант, можно фильтровать селекторы

```
$('div[class^="ymaps-"]').filter(()=>{
    return this.class.match(/\d-route-content__taxi-link-text/);
}).on('click', ()=>{

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Такой возможности нас сегодняшний день (версия 2.1.69) нет.